# ddev behind corporate proxy

Tags: proxy, ddev

I want the ddev web container to use my corporate proxy settings.
Else when i run `composer diagnose` i end up with this:

```
uid_1000@d24b5fb17f37:/var/www/html$ composer diagnose
Checking platform settings: OK
Checking git settings: OK
Checking http connectivity to packagist: [Composer\Downloader\TransportException] The "http://repo.packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: Connection timed out
Checking https connectivity to packagist: [Composer\Downloader\TransportException] The "https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: Connection timed out
Checking github.com rate limit: FAIL
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] The "https://api.github.com/rate_limit" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: Connection timed out
Checking disk free space: OK
Checking pubkeys: 
Tags Public Key Fingerprint: 57815BA2 7E54DC31 7ECC7CC5 573090D0  87719BA6 8F3BB723 4E5D42D0 84A14642
Dev Public Key Fingerprint: 4AC45767 E5EC2265 2F0C1167 CBBB8A2B  0C708369 153E328C AD90147D AFE50952
OK
Checking composer version: 

  [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                                                          
  The "https://getcomposer.org/versions" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: Connection timed out  


diagnose
```

And i can't use composer properly.

I need a way to pass the environnement variables `HTTP_PROXY`, `HTTPS_PROXY` and `NO_PROXY` to the container, how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update :**

Well, after reading a bit of **docker** documentation, there is an existing way to define a proxy properly... See https://docs.docker.com/network/proxy/

By creating on the host the file `~/.docker/config.json` with

```
{
 "proxies":
 {
   "default":
   {
     "httpProxy": "http://ip:port",
     "httpsProxy": "http://user:password@ip:port,
     "noProxy": "*.test.example.com,.example2.com"
   }
 }
}
```

then `ddev restart` docker will automatically set the needed ENV vars, lowercase and uppercase.

With this, `composer` works, `wget` works. `apt` still doesn't works form inside the container, because it still need proxy settings in a `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20proxyconf` file, but it works from a `.ddev/web-build/Dockerfile`, i think that's enough :)

Comment: I'm not sure if we need both lower and uppercase, but it's look like wget need those in lowercase, although convention is uppercase for env vars...

Comment: I'd be surprised of anything uses $http_proxy or $https_proxy. Thanks for this!